# SharePoint Link Tools (Ribbon) Remove Link does not delete link

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I have a SP 2010 Publishing Site (14.0.4762.1000). It has a contenttype containing a Publishing Hyperlink (SPFieldLink). Inserting a link with the Link Tools (part of the ribbon) works fine, but I can't delete the link once I set it.

For quick reproduction:

- Create a Publishing Portal site
- Create a column of type Publishing Hyperlink
- Add the column to de Welcome Page contenttype
- Navigate to the Press Releases page
- View information -> Edit
- Add a link to the newly created column and save the page
- Open it again, remove the link (the link is visually removed, it even says: Click here to add a new Hyperlink)
- Save the page again
- Now open the page again.
- In our situation, the message 'Click here...' is gone, and if you view the source our original link is still there, but there is no text inside it.

I did some testing on it and these are the results:

- It occurs on dev and prod server with a custom solution installed
- It occurs on a server with no custom solution installed (clean install)
- It also occurs on the 'Adventure Works' site (both on a clean install and on a server with custom solution)
- It occurs both when creating a sitecolumn of type Publishing Hyperlink through API and UI
- When viewed with firebug the 'deleted' link is still in the href property, but the text property is empty
- Tested on IE/FF
- When viewing with Sharepoint Manager 2010, the link is still in de DB (with no text property as stated above)
- It happens on Dutch and English sites

Anyone familiar with this behaviour? Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I currently have exactly the same issue in a publishing site. I'm looking into it. Let you know if I find anything.

Found your topic on social MSDN. Apperently this is a bug in SP2010.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/sharepoint2010general/thread/8ce468ec-096b-4ad2-a1e9-0bfb93cecf95

Currently there is a powershell fix (not really an option for me)

http://vasya10.wordpress.com/2011/06/07/inconspicuous-sharepoint-quirks-2/

Hope this helps.